# Puppet syntax issue when configuring a Prometheus scrape on an SNMP exporter

Tags: puppet, prometheus

### Some context

I have an SNMP exporter running as a service on a server which allows me to access the data of some PDU using the following URL: `http://my.host.name:9116/snmp?target=10.0.1.200&auth=public_v1&module=apcups`

I have a Prometheus server which I have configured using puppet on the same host. I want to add a scrape job to retrieve the information provided by the PDUs.

Relying on the tutorial [on this page](https://grafana.com/blog/2022/02/01/an-advanced-guide-to-network-monitoring-with-grafana-and-prometheus/#running-the-snmp_exporter) and some other sources, I was able to confirm that manually modifying the `/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yaml` file to insert the following gives me the expected result. For shortness I only include the relevant part of the configuration file.

```
- job_name: snmp_scrapper
  scrape_interval: 60s
  scrape_timeout: 10s
  metrics_path: /snmp
  static_configs:
  - targets:
    - my.host.name:9116
  params:
    target: [10.0.1.200]          # IP of the PDU on the private network
    auth: [public_v1]             # authentication method
    module: [apcups]              # module to retrieve APC PDU/UPS information
```

This works exactly as I expected, I can plot my power consumption in Prometheus and Grafana etc.

### My Issue

To configure Puppet to produce the prometheus configuration above, I added the following job in the profile in which prometheus is configured (I have another job scraping node_exporter on a number of hosts from which I was able to take inspiration from):

```
        {
          'job_name'        => 'snmp_scrapper',
          'scrape_interval' => '60s',
          'scrape_timeout'  => '10s',
          'metrics_path'    => '/snmp',
          'static_configs'  => [{ 'targets' => ['my.host.name:9116'], }],
          'params' => {
            'target' => '[10.0.1.200]',
            'auth' => '[public_v1]',
            'module' => '[apcups]',
          }
        },
```

The problem is this produces the erroneous `prometheus.yaml` file below with additional quotes around the `metrics_path` and three elements inside `params`.

```
 - job_name: snmp_scrapper
   scrape_interval: 60s
   scrape_timeout: 10s
   metrics_path: "/snmp"
   static_configs:
   - targets:
     - my.host.name:9116
   params:
     target: "[10.0.1.200]"
     auth: "[public_v1]"
     module: "[apcups]"
```

The configuration parser of Prometheus then fails with the following error:

```
  FAILED: parsing YAML file /etc/prometheus/prometheus.yaml20231023-1016214-j3iqrx: yaml: unmarshal errors:
  line 47: cannot unmarshal !!str `[10.0.1...` into []string
  line 48: cannot unmarshal !!str `[public...` into []string
  line 49: cannot unmarshal !!str `[apcups]` into []string
```

Naively, I thought removing the quotes around `/snmp` and around the square brackets in the params would fix my problem, i.e.:

```
          'job_name'        => 'snmp_scrapper',
          'scrape_interval' => '60s',
          'scrape_timeout'  => '10s',
          'metrics_path'    => /snmp,
          'static_configs'  => [{ 'targets' => ['my.host.name:9116'], }],
          'params' => {
            'target' => [10.0.1.200],
            'auth' => [public_v1],
            'module' => [apcups],
```

But this results in a Puppet syntax error.

### My question

How do I obtain the desired `/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yaml` showed at the top of this question through Puppet? My guess is there must be some sort of syntax that allows the production of a string of text without the quotes but I don't know how.

I am using Puppet version 8.2.0 and the [puppet/prometheus](https://forge.puppet.com/modules/puppet/prometheus) v13.3.0 module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're halfway there - you don't want to remove the quotes, but move them:

```
'job_name'        => 'snmp_scrapper',
      'scrape_interval' => '60s',
      'scrape_timeout'  => '10s',
      'metrics_path'    => '/snmp',
      'static_configs'  => [{ 'targets' => ['my.example.com:9116'], }],
      'params' => {
        'target' => ['10.0.1.200'],
        'auth' => ['public_v1'],
        'module' => ['apcups'],
```

In both YAML and the Puppet DDL, `[` and `]` indicate arrays, in this case arrays of strings; `target: [10.0.1.200]` in YAML is a single-element array containing a single string (`10.0.1.200`), which could also be written as:

```
      target:
        - 10.0.1.200
```

To generate correct Prometheus config, you need to ensure that `target`, `auth` and `module` are generated as arrays, which simply means that they need to be Puppet arrays on the way in. This means having the `[` and `]` outside of the quotes, as they're part of the language syntax rather than part of the strings, but then because Puppet requires strings to be quoted, your actual values (`10.0.1.200`, `public_v1` etc) need to be quoted, otherwise you get the Puppet syntax errors you're reporting.

The Puppet Prometheus module simply converts `scrape_configs` directly into YAML, so Puppet arrays are expressed as YAML arrays - and erroneous Puppet strings get expressed as YAML strings, even when you don't want them to be.